# tornado, How to map URL and handler with a regular expression way

Tags: python, tornado

I want to map "/aaa.jpg" and "/bbb.jpg".... with the same Handler

I write the code as`(r"/*.jpg", ImageHandler"),` it that correct ? It doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r"/*.jpg"` is a file glob pattern, not a regular expression. The equivalent regular expression would be `r"/.*\.jpg"`.